# Choosing some specific fields from a record with awk

Tags: awk

Suppose I have a file which has only one record with 100 fields:

`a1 a2 a3 a4 ... a100`

where all the `a`'s are numbers. Is there any efficient methods to pick out all the numbers which are less than a certain number, eg,`300` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the Record Selector in `awk`

```
awk -v RS=" " '$0<300' file
```

```
echo "100 200 300 400" | awk -v RS=" " '$0<300'
100
200
```

```
echo "100 200 300 400" | awk -v RS=" " -v ORS=" " '$0<300'
100 200
```

or

```
echo "100 200 300 400 125" | awk '$0<300' RS=" " ORS=" "
100 200 125
```

---

To make a clean exit, I have added the new line at the end. Heads up for `Ed` and `Steve` :)

```
echo "100 200 300 400 150" | awk -v RS=" " -v ORS=" " '$0<300; END {print "\n"}'
100 200 150
```

If an extra blank line is not what you like while last number is true, add `\n` to `RS`, but this will make it less portable.

```
echo "100 200 300 400 150" | awk -v RS=" |\n" -v ORS=" " '$0<300; END {print "\n"}'
100 200 150
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. They are good. But how to directly keep the structure of the file unchanged. Because the result shows that each number now become a record.

Comment: @jiadong You can set the Output Record Selector to get it back to one line. If your file has only one record as you write, this should be ok.

Comment: Its not QUITE that simple though because the final number will have the `\n` at the end of it so you need to deal with that somehow.

Comment: Only difference I can see if last number is within range, you get a new line after last number in output, and if its not within range, no newline.  Since OP only have one `record` = one line, this is no problem. To get same behavior, you could use `awk '$0<300' RS=" |\n" ORS=" "`

Comment: @Jotne: That makes the output consistent at least, but I disagree with you that that isn't a problem. Ed Morton is correct - it always best practice to print the carriage return. You would need another block in there, like: `END { print "\n" }`. That said, a multi-character `RS` isn't ideal anyway, unless you're willing to sacrifice portability.

Comment: `-v RS=" |\n" -v ORS=" "` will add a spurious blank char at the end of the line which is usually undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

The difficult part of this question is producing a solution that doesn't add leading or trailing spaces and/or newlines to the output, regardless of which position the fields are that need to be printed (some will behave differently when printing the first or last field).

This will do it:

```
$ echo "1 4 2 5 3 6" |
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i<4) { printf "%s%s", ofs, $i; ofs=OFS } print "" }'
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i<300) print $i;}' input.txt
```

Input:

```
100 200 300 400
```

Output:

```
100
200
```

To get output in one line:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i<300) {printf j==1?OFS$i:$i;j=1;}}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

My preferred solution for your task here would be to not use AWK, but to instead use Perl in autosplit mode. Perl gives you access to a [join()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) function that makes your task really quite trivial:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5 6" | perl -lane 'print join (" ", grep { $_ < 4 } @F)'
```

Results:

```
1 2 3
```

Advantages:

- Writes just once per line of input, as opposed to 100 (or more) writes per line of input as with the other answers here.
- Avoids having to futz with record or field separators, leading or lagging white-space, newlines etc.
- Highly readable, maintainable blah blah.

If you *must* use AWK because this is homework, you could always role your own `join()` function. If that's the case, then you may be interested in [this](http://awk.info/?gawk/array/join.awk) one.

Comment: Couldn't agree more that perl is suitable in this case.

Comment: Though you could avoid `join` by making use of `$OFS` or `$,=" "`.

Comment: @devnull: Thanks! A good suggestion, but perhaps using `$"` would be more fitting here. For example: `perl -lane '@F = grep { $_ < 4 } @F; print "@F"'`. With double quotes, we get the interpolation and since the array separator defaults to a single space, we get exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: wrt `Writes just once per line of input, as opposed to 100 (or more) writes per line of input` - I'm not sure that's desirable. I don't know about perl but with awk at least, string concatenation is slower than writing to stdout due to the memory management associated with growing strings.

Comment: @EdMorton: Perl's string concatenation is slow too. But the join() function works differently. I found [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch24_02.htm). You will need to search for 'join' (sorry). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104493/performance-with-perl-strings).